# Relation between a vector $x$, its Vandermonde matrix $V(x)$ and non-linear system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

Consider the vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^N$ and its elementwise power $x^k = x \odot x \odot \cdots  \odot x$ for $k$ times.
What can we say about the vector space spanned by $x$ and its powers $x^k$ for $k=0, \ldots, K$?

Consider also the following system of equations $A1=0, Ax=0, Ax^2=0, \ldots, Ax^K=0$. When does the system have a solution?

**EDIT**: after some comments, I realized I was not sufficiently informative on my question. So here is my attempt to clarify some doubts and expand the question.

My question is:  when can we say that we can find a vector $x \in {\bf R}^N$ such that it satisfies:

$$A \underbrace{[1 \; x \; x^{\odot2} \ldots x^{\odot K}]}_{V}=0$$
where $K<N$, and $A$ is a $M \times N$ matrix.
The matrix $V$ is a Vandermonde matrix consisting of $K+1$ columns. By rewriting the above expression as:

$$V^\top A^\top=0$$
we see that we are searching for the solution of a non-linear system of equations on $x$. Assume that $x_i \neq x_j$ in at least $K+1$ entries, so that $V$ is full column-rank. The fact that all the rows of $A$ must sum to $0$ seems also very restrictive.

How can I find a possible solution? I was also thinking on the relationship of this problem with *polynomial regression*: there we have the Vandermonde matrix $V$ and we try to find the coefficients $a_i$; here is the opposite, we have the coefficients, but we want to find a "good" vector $x$ such that the $a_i^\top x^{\odot k}=0$ for different $k$.

Comment: Let $P$ be a set of $0,1$-vectors, 
$$
M=\cup_{\alpha\in\mathbb{R}}\alpha P
$$ 
If $x\notin M$, then $\operatorname{dim}\langle x, x^2\rangle=2$.
 
If $U$ is a null-space of $A$ and $D$ is a matrix, then $D^{-1}(U)$ is a null-space of $AD$, where $D^{-1}(U)$ is the preimage $U$ under $D$.

Comment: Could you give me an explanation about it? Or at least, how does it translate in terms of $x$? When can I say that $Ax=0$ implies $Ax^k=0$ for different powers k?

Comment: Not very clear questions. What do you mean by that? For which $A$ is the statement $Ax=0\Rightarrow Ax^2$ true for every vector $x$? Or for which $A$ and $x$ is the statement true? It's very unclear.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What I mean to say is: I have $A$ and I want to find a vector $x$ such that $Ax^i=0$ for different powers $i=0, 1, \ldots$. I was wondering whether finding a solution $x$ would implies that also its powers are solution. But my intuition is that they are not.

Comment: I also want to clarify your problem. So we have a matrix $A$. We need to find out if the following system of equations $Ax=0,\ Ax^2=0,\ldots,\ A=x^k$, where $k\geq2$, has a solution. It remains to understand what is the upper bound for $k$? I find the problem interesting in this formulation. Why don't you correct your question.

Comment: I updated the question. I clarified myself the question while writing. Thanks!

Comment: It seems to me that it also makes sense to correct the title of the question.

Comment: I have corrected the title, updated and expanded the question.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that you are excluding $\vec{x}^{\circ0}=(1,1,\dots,1)$.  The theory is much more natural once this vector is included.

The matrix consisting of the first $N$ Hadamard powers (from $0$ to $N-1$) of $\vec{x}$ is known as the (transpose of) the [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) $\mathcal{V}(\vec{x})$.  Simply symbol-pushing, \begin{align*}
&\vec{0}=\mathcal{A}\vec{x}^{\circ0}=\mathcal{A}\vec{x}=\dots \\
&\iff\mathcal{A}\mathcal{V}(\vec{x})^{\mathsf{T}}=0 \\
&\iff\mathcal{V}(\vec{x})\mathcal{A}^{\mathsf{T}}=0
\end{align*}  It is also straightforward to see that $\mathcal{V}(\vec{x})$ is full-rank iff $\vec{x}$ has no repeated entries.  Moreover, one can reduce to the "no repeated entries" case by removing the duplicates.

Thus we see:

- If $\vec{x}$ has exactly $k$ distinct entries, then $\{\vec{x}^{\circ j}\}_{j\in[k]}$ are a basis on their span.
- Each row of $\mathcal{A}$ corresponds to a polynomial vanishing on the entries of $\vec{x}$.

To remove the dependence on $\vec{x}^{\circ0}$, note that this is the same as multiplying the $j$<sup>th</sup> row of $\mathcal{V}(\vec{x})$ by $x_j$, which then carries over to the determinant.  Thus the above still holds as long as we consider zeros in $\vec{x}$ to be duplicates of an "implicit hidden $0$".

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand your message, but I did not get on how I can find such a solution. I have updated my question to introduce also the Vandermonde matrix.